# Fulltext Search in SQL Server 2008 Step by step

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

How to get started with **Fulltext Search in SQL Server 2008**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read these links:

[SQL SERVER – 2008 – Creating Full Text Catalog and Full Text Search](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)
[Using Full Text Search in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/full_text_search_2008_p1.aspx)
[Setting Up Full Text Search: A Step-by-step Guide](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438211/Setting-Up-Full-Text-Search-A-Step-by-step-Guide.htm)
[Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)
[SQL Server 2008 Full Text Search Best Practices from the SQL CAT Team](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/11/sql-server-2008-full-text-search-best.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would add those links from Simple Talk's web site:

- [Understanding Full-Text Indexing in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)
- [SQL Server Full Text Search Language Features](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features/)
- [SQL Server Full Text Search Language Features - Part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features,-part-2/)